# Estou inserindo um array no banco de dados através de um script que fiz mas salva apenas o primeiro e o segundo digito

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estou inserindo um *array* no banco de dados através de um *script* que fiz, mas salva apenas o primeiro e o segundo digito.

**HTML:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 //ADICIONAR MAIS CAMPOS OUTRO SCRIPT
   
 $(function() {
  var spanCont = $('#addingt_pizza');
   var add_btn_pizza = $('button[data-id="1"]');
  var i = 1;

$(add_btn_pizza).click(function() {
$('<br/><input type="text" name="ingt_pizza['+i+']" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o ingrediente que pretende adicionar ex: sal, ovo, tomate, batata, etc." required/>').appendTo(spanCont);
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<form action="process_novo.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="text">Ingredientes:</label>
 <span id="addingt_pizza">
   <input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o ingrediete que pretende adicionar ex: sal, ovo, tomate, batata, etc." >
 </span><br>
    <button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default"><img src="../imagens/add.png" alt="" width="15"> Campos</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Arquivo PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['adicionar_pizza'])) {

    $nome_pizza = $_POST['nome_pizza'];
    $preco_pizza = $_POST['preco_pizza'];
    $data = date("d-m-Y H:s");
    $imagem_pizza = $_FILES['imagem_pizza']['name'];

    $ingredient = $_POST['ingt_pizza'];

    $ingredientes = implode(',', (array)$ingredient);                   


    if (file_exists("imagens_pizzas/$imagem_pizza")) {
        $a = 1;
        while (file_exists("imagens_pizzas/[$a]$imagem_pizza")) {
                $a++;
            }
            $imagem_pizza = "[".$a."]".$imagem_pizza;
    }

    $insert_pizza = "INSERT INTO pizza (nome, ingredientes, preco, imagem, data) VALUES ('$nome_pizza', '$ingredientes', '$preco_pizza', '$imagem_pizza', '$data')";                        

    $resul_pizza=mysqli_query($conexao, $insert_pizza);

    (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem_pizza']['tmp_name'], "imagens_pizzas/".$imagem_pizza));

    if ($resul_pizza) 
    { 
        echo "<script>alert('Guardado com sucesso!');location.href='index.php';</script>;";

    }else{

        echo "<script>alert('Nao foi possivel guardar. Ocorreu um erro por favor, tente novamente!');location.href='index.php';</script>;";
    }        

}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está criando vários campos com o mesmo nome. Quando clicamos em `campos`, o valor da variável `i` não muda, continua sempre como `1`. Isso gera vários campos com o mesmo nome, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[1]"  />
<input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[1]"  />
<input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[1]"  />
<input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[1]"  />
<input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[1]"  />
```

O correto é somar um, ao valor da variável. Você pode fazer isso com `i++;` ao clicar no botão, por exemplo:

```
  $(add_btn_pizza).click(function() {
    $(' .. ').appendTo(spanCont);

    i++; //Essa operação equivale a i = i + 1
  });
```

> **Dica:** Isso é opcional, você pode simplesmente criar vários campos com o nome `name="ingt_pizza[]"`

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var spanCont = $('#addingt_pizza');
  var add_btn_pizza = $('button[data-id="1"]');

  $(add_btn_pizza).click(function() {
    $('<br/><input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o ingrediente que pretende adicionar ex: sal, ovo, tomate, batata, etc." required />').appendTo(spanCont);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process_novo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Ingredientes:</label>
    <span id="addingt_pizza">
   <input type="text" name="ingt_pizza[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o ingrediete que pretende adicionar ex: sal, ovo, tomate, batata, etc." >
 </span><br>
    <button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default"><img src="../imagens/add.png" alt="" width="15"> Campos</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, valeu mesmo

Comment: @JosePinto Se possível marque como resolvido, caso tenha ajudado. Qualquer coisa só perguntar.

Comment: Foi resolvido sim! Valdeir Psr, muito obrigado. Mas nao tenho ideia onde marcar que esta resolvido, tem algum sitio para marcar caso tenha resolvido aqui no StackOverflow